# Excel viewer lib

Tags: javascript, html, excel, xls, xlsx

I'd like to allow users to view Microsoft Excel files by browser and choose data from it's sheets for further manipulation. How to do it?

I tried http://oss.sheetjs.com/ but showing data is not working for sheets with a lot of number data and merged cells, for example for this file: http://stat.gov.pl/download/gfx/portalinformacyjny/pl/defaultaktualnosci/5502/11/13/1/wyniki_finansowe_podmiotow_gospodarczych_1-6m_2015.xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tired http://viewerjs.org?
You will need to save your excel file as ODP. You can do this by save-as the excel as "OpenDocument Format".

Comment: .odp is an ODF Presentation, you probably thought about .ods filetype. Do you know any open-source working parser which can handle such a sophisticated excel files and convert them to .ods format? without parsing it your solution is unfortunatelly useless.

Comment: I tried `unoconv -f ods *.xlsx` and it looks quite good. I'll test it and let you know.